# Proving that polynomials belonging to a certain family are reducible

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, fields

In an [article](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-potential-analogue-of-Schinzel%27s-hypothesis-for-Bender-Wittenberg/cc4b8b7082c3ac64809adf5d333ed1c9a6d83f01), I've found the following result. Unfortunately, it was derived from a general, somewhat complicated theory, that would be cumbersome for this result alone.

> Assume that $\mathbb F_p$ is the field with $p$ elements, and that we choose an integer $a$ with $1< a < 4p$, such that $a$ be coprime to $p(p-1)$ (for example, $a = 2p - 1$ is suitable). Let $t$ be transcendental over $\mathbb F_p$, and set $K = \mathbb F_p(t)$. Consider the polynomial $$P(X) = X^{4p} +t^a$$ in $K[X]$.
>
> Then for every $f\in \mathbb F_p[t]$, $P(f)$ is reducible in $\mathbb F_p[t]$.

I would like a direct proof of this result. Any idea?

Comment: There appears to be a typo in the setup; what role does $b$ play?

Comment: thx. question edited.

Comment: If you are interested in this, you probably want to read Conrad, Conrad and Gross https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/articles/genuszero.pdf . See also the expository https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/articles/texel.pdf .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It follows from [this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103036322) result of Swan: If $t$ divides $f(t)$ there is nothing to do. So assume that this is not he case. Then with $F(t)=P(f(t))=f(t)^{4p}+t^a$, $F'(t)=at^{a-1}$ and $F(t)$ is separable. From this one easily gets that the discriminant of $F(t)$ is a square in $\mathbb F_p$ (see the alternative formula for the discriminant at the beginning of the article of Swan). By Swan's result, the number of irreducible factors of $F(t)$ is congruent to $\deg F(t)=4p\deg f$ mod $2$, hence it is even and therefore $>1$.

*Note added later:* In fact the special case needed here is already due to Dickson, as pointed out by Swan in his paper. The argument is easy: If $F(t)$ is separable of degree $n$ and irreducible, then its Galois group contains an $n$-cycle. If $n$ is even, then this $n$-cycle is an odd permutation, so the discriminant of $F(t)$ is not a square. (Assuming that we are working over a finite field of odd characteristic.)

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I would like to insert this example in an article I am writing. Could I cite you?

Comment: @MikeTeX Of course, you may write that I pointed to Swan's paper.

Comment: Thx. The article is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.14711. You are cited at the beginning of Sec. 7.